# How to set up Types with Graphql Codegen

Tags: typescript, vue.js, graphql-codegen, urql

I have a Vue 3 component using Urql to query a Hasura graphql endpoint. I have managed to get the fairly simple query working, and am now trying to make the component Type safe.

I am using graphql Codegen to build the types, and it is generating a Types file, but there are errors thrown in the resultant generated file.

I am a bit new to Typescript so hoping someone might be able to put me right. I am keen to resolve the issues reported in the generated Types file.

I have provided the following:

1. Copy of the working ListTodos.vue component.
2. Abreviated copy of the Generated Types file (graphql.d.ts). The error occurs at lines 975 - 989, so I have provided a short version of the file with the relevant lines only.
3. Copy of the errors reported
4. Copy of my codegen.js configuration file.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

**1. ListTodos.vue**

```
<script setup lang="ts">
    import { useQuery, gql } from '@urql/vue'

    const FETCH_TODOS = gql`
        query {
            todos {
                title
                user {
                    name
                }
                is_public
            }
        }
    `
    const result = useQuery({ query: FETCH_TODOS })
</script>

<template>
    <div v-if="result.fetching.value">Loading..</div>
    <div v-else-if="result.error.value">{{ result.error.value }}</div>
    <div v-else>
        <ul>
            <li v-for="todo of result.data.value.todos">
                <h4>{{ todo.title }}</h4>
                <p>{{ todo.user.name }}</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>
```

**2. Generated Types (abreviated) showing the error underlining**
[image: 2. Generated Types showing the error underlining]

**3. Errors**

[image]

**4. Codegen.js configuration file**

```
module.exports = {
    overwrite: true,
    generates: {
        './src/generated/graphql.d.ts': {
            schema: [
                {
                    'https://sample-backend-for-hasura-tutorial.hasura.app/v1/graphql': {
                        headers: {
                            'x-hasura-role': 'admin',
                            'x-hasura-admin-secret': 'secret',
                        },
                    },
                },
            ],
            documents: ['./src/**/*.vue'],
            plugins: ['typescript', 'typescript-operations', 'typescript-vue-urql'],
            config: {
                preResolveTypes: true,
                skipTypename: false,
                enumsAsTypes: true,
                constEnums: true,
            },
        },
    },
}
```

Comment: I have progressed a little...

Comment: added "noGraphQLTag: true," to the end of the above config (despite it being deprecated)  and the issue with the gql tag went away

Comment: Replaced by:
export const Document = {"kind":"Document","definitions":[{"kind":"OperationDefinition","operation":"query","selectionSet":{"kind":"SelectionSet","selections":[{"kind":"Field","name":{"kind":"Name","value":"todos"},"selectionSet":{"kind":"SelectionSet","selections":[{"kind":"Field","name":{"kind":"Name","value":"title"}},{"kind":"Field","name":{"kind":"Name","value":"user"},"selectionSet":{"kind":"SelectionSet","selections":[{"kind":"Field","name":{"kind":"Name","value":"name"}}]}},{"kind":"Field","name":{"kind":"Name","value":"is_public"}}]}}]}}]} as unknown as DocumentNode;

Comment: Above statement throws the following error:
A 'const' initializer in an ambient context must be a string or numeric literal or literal enum reference.ts(1254)
as well as the last 4 errors shown above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - I seem to have resolved the problem.

I removed the plugin 'typescript-vue-urql' from the config which seems counter intuitive, but the generated file then had no issues.

I also added a name for the query, then imported this 'name' from the Types file, and then typed the useQuery function.